# qiita や zenn にある、記事のスクロールに合わせてフォーカスが変わる見出しに名前はありますか?

Tags: ui

https://zenn.dev や https://qiita.com の記事は、記事の右側に heading の一覧が表示され、記事をスクロールしていくと、そのフォーカスが切り替わっていきます。

[image: zenn.dev の記事のスクリーンショット]

( ^ ページをスクロールしていくと、今ヘッダーが active であると表示される。この場合は「理由4. 障害に巻き込まれる可能性を抑えるため」が active になっている)

このような、記事の scroll に合わせてフォーカスが変わっていく table of contents には、名前はついていますか? というのも、例えば Vue ないし React を使っているときに、ライブラリでこれを実現するようなものがあればそれを使いたいと思ったとき、どのように検索したら良いのかが分からなかったので、質問しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Sticky** Table of Contents" 辺りでしょうか。

例:
[Sticky Table of Contents with Scrolling Active States](https://css-tricks.com/sticky-table-of-contents-with-scrolling-active-states/)

Comment: 当該記事において、質問の指している部分は"Scrolling Active States"ではないでしょうか。Stickyは`position: sticky`を用いるような固定ナビゲーションのほうを指しているようですが。。。